# URL Rewrting in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have windows2008R2 server, I have installed ARR2 for URL rewriting , buts its looking there is no processing happening...Please suggest me the solution....

Answer (score 0):

You should use Failed Request Tracing to understand why the routing/rewriting is not happening. Also I would add for Rewriting you do not need ARR, you can just install URL Rewrite, that is unless you are rewriting to a different AppPool or a different server.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/467/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules/